# Socket.io 1.0 - Event to room only broadcastet, I want to emit to everyone (including sender)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

according to the new [docs](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/):

> simply use to or in (they are the same) when broadcasting or emitting:

```
io.to('some room').emit('some event');
```

And it works like expected in a context like

```
    socket.on('event', function (data) {
        //do some action
        socket.to('room').emit('response_event', data);
    });
```

But I want to send 'some event' not only to the other participants in the room but also to the sender himself.

According to previous versions, I expected a behavior like

```
io.to('some room').broadcast('some event'); //to everyone else
io.to('some room').emit('some event'); //to everyone else and sending socket
```

As a workaround, I first sent the event to the sending socket, then broadcast it. But that seems dirty to me

```
socket.on('event', function (data) {
    //do some action
    socket.emit('response_event', data);
    socket.to('room').emit('response_event', data);
});
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `io.to('some room').emit('some event');` still works in Socket.IO 1.0. Just change `socket.to` to `io.to` in your sample

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`socket.to('room').emit` works like the former broadcast (send to everyone except sender).
`io.sockets.to('room').emit` emits to everyone in room.

for namespaces use `io.of('/namespace').to('room').emit`

Source: personal experience after having searched the docs for quite some time.

Comment: I don't think the answer is correct in verion 1.3.5. I've done testing. `socket.to('room').emit` will emits to everyone except the sender.

Comment: Just found out that the answer is badly worded. IIRC the former broadcast sent to everyone except the sender; edited to be clear.